# What is the best way to push data to the device?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, push, android-c2dm

I am making a web app that needs to communicate with the Android phone, what is the best way to get data from the web app to the phone? I have heard of C2DM but I don't know any good guides for it. I have tried polling, but that is way too heavy on the battery. Whats the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What kind of data? HTML? JSON? etc

Comment: @Sbossb Just simple, maximum 200-300 characters of data. Most likely will be base64 encoded aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is the following: using C2DM your phone should just receive a notification about the event. Basing on this event you connect to a resource and download necessary information. [This](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) and [this](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) resources I used when I've tried to develop my C2DM application.

Answer (score 0):

As well as C2DM you could also look at services such as [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) or if the communication with the device is interactive then you could look at a [realtime web technology](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide).